# Assigning values to custom columns based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transpose

So, this is an example of a dataset i'm working with ([link here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pfeNbSQK7KWaaQcEGGxzgDyfX8c1_GwR))

```
brand  model  column1  column2  column3  category  sub category  value
Dell   a      aa                bb       cat1      sc1           aaa
Dell   a      aa                bb       cat1      sc2           bbb
Dell   a      aa                cc       cat2      sc1           ccc
Dell   b      aa       bb                cat1      sc1           ddd
Dell   b      aa       bb                cat2      sc1           eee
Dell   b      aa       bb       cc       cat2                    fff
Asus   c      aa       cc       bb       cat1      sc1           ggg
Asus   c      aa       cc       bb       cat1                    hhh
Asus   c      aa                         cat1      sc2           iii
Asus   d      aa       cc       bb       cat1      sc1           jjj
Asus   d      aa       bb       bb       cat1      sc2           kkk
Asus   d      aa       bb       bb       cat1      sc3           lll
```

What I need to do first is separate unique models based on brand, model, column1-3 which i do by this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("abhorrent.csv")
noDupes = df[["brand", "model name", "column1", "column2", "column3"]].drop_duplicates().copy()
```

That returns a table like this:

```
brand    model  column1  column2  column3
Dell     a      aa                bb
Dell     a      aa                cc
Dell     b      aa       bb
Dell     b      aa       bb       cc
Asus     c      aa       cc       bb
Asus     c      aa 
Asus     d      aa       cc       bb
Asus     d      aa       bb       bb
```

However, I need to create columns based on the category, sub category and value, and assign their values.

The columns names are the concats of category and sub category in which I need to put in the values of those pairs:

```
cat1_sc1
cat1_sc2
cat1_sc3
cat1_blank
cat2_sc1
cat2_blank
```

The columns don't need to be auto generated, I can hardcode them in.

The issue is that I don't know how to populate values in those columns based on the non unique dataframe.

The end result I'm looking for is this:

```
brand    model  column1  column2  column3  cat1_sc1  cat1_sc2  cat1_sc3  cat1_blank  cat2_sc1  cat2_blank
Dell     a      aa                bb       aaa       bbb               
Dell     a      aa                cc                                                 ccc   
Dell     b      aa       bb                ddd                                       eee   
Dell     b      aa       bb       cc                                                           fff
Asus     c      aa       cc       bb       ggg                           hhh       
Asus     c      aa                                   iii               
Asus     d      aa       cc       bb       jjj                    
Asus     d      aa       bb       bb                 kkk       lll
```

I was able to do it in PostrgreSQL, where my solution was originally developed, using one UPDATE for each of the predefined columns. Something along the lines of:

```
#fill the cat1_sc1 column
UPDATE transposed_table
SET cat1_sc1 = subquery.value
FROM
    (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE category = 'cat1' AND sub_category = 'sc1') subquery
WHERE brand = subquery.brand AND model = subquery.model etc
```

**EDIT: my actual CSV has close to 500k rows**

Comment: Are You familiar with the [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function of pandas DataFrames ? E.g. ```df.pivot(columns='category')```

Comment: @Antihead So I've been looking into the pivot functions and it doesn't look too good. I'm having problems with aggregation. It seems that by default pivot_table expects a numeric type. When I use just pivot it says that the Length of passed values i 12, index implies 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of my colleague...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

GROUP_BY = ["brand", "model", "column1", "column2", "column3"]
CATEGORY = "category"
SUB_CATEGORY = "sub category"
VALUE = "value"
GROUPING = "grouping"

def combine_model(group):
    def combine_value(value):
        return value.str.cat(sep=" || ") #in case of multiple values for one category / sub category combination
    value = group.groupby(GROUPING)[VALUE].apply(combine_value)
    group.loc[:, value.index.tolist()] = value.values
    return group

data = pd.read_csv("abhorrent.csv")

for col in GROUP_BY + [SUB_CATEGORY, VALUE]:
    data[col].fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
data[GROUPING] = data[CATEGORY] + "_" + data[SUB_CATEGORY]
columns = data[GROUPING].drop_duplicates().tolist()
for col in columns:
    data[col] = np.nan
data = data.groupby(GROUP_BY).apply(combine_model)
data.drop_duplicates(subset=GROUP_BY, inplace=True)
```

Rest is only about removing unnecessary columns...

Thank you all who suggested a solution or left a comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
noDupes['cat1_sc1'] = df[(df["category"] == "cat1") & (df["sub category"] == "sc1")]["value"]
```

You would have to do this over all categories and sub_categories, but I think you get the idea.

## EDIT:

Full Code to get it all running:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("abhorrent.csv")

cats = df["category"].drop_duplicates().tolist()
sub_cats = df["sub category"].drop_duplicates().tolist()
cat_sc_s = []
for cat in cats:
    for sc in sub_cats:
        name = str(cat) + '_' + str(sc)
        cat_sc_s.append(name)
        df[name] = df[(df["category"] == cat) & (df["sub category"] == sc)]["value"]

noDupes = df[["brand", "model", "column1", "column2", "column3"] + cat_sc_s].drop_duplicates().copy()
print(noDupes)
```

## EDIT 2:

That was a bit of a pain in the **** :D But it became something personal at some point :D

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("abhorrent.csv")

df = df.fillna('')
cats = df["category"].drop_duplicates().tolist()
sub_cats = df["sub category"].drop_duplicates().tolist()
cat_sc_s = []
for cat in cats:
    for sc in sub_cats:
        if sc == '':
            sc = 'blanc'
        name = str(cat) + '_' + str(sc)
        cat_sc_s.append(name)
        df[name] = df[(df["category"] == cat) & (df["sub category"] == sc)]["value"]


df = df.fillna('')
df = df.groupby(["brand", "model", "column1", "column2", "column3"], as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
df = df.drop(['category', 'sub category', 'value'], axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Test it and let me know

It changes the order, however.
Result:

```
  brand model column1 column2 column3 cat1_sc1 cat1_sc2 cat1_blanc cat1_sc3 cat2_sc1 cat2_sc2 cat2_blanc cat2_sc3
0  Asus     c      aa                               iii                                                          
1  Asus     c      aa      cc      bb     ggg                                                                    
2  Asus     d      aa      bb      bb              kkk                  lll                                      
3  Asus     d      aa      cc      bb      jjj                                                                   
4  Dell     a      aa              bb     aaa       bbb                                                          
5  Dell     a      aa              cc                                            ccc                             
6  Dell     b      aa      bb             ddd                                    eee                             
7  Dell     b      aa      bb      cc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. When I assign it to a variable, it correctly returns a series.

`test = df[(df["category"] == "cat1") & (df["sub category"] == "sc1")]["value"]`

However, when I try assing it to a new column as you proposed all values are nan. Probably because the noDupes df and the series returned by your code are not the same length?

In other words, not all unique models necessarilly have rows with cat1 + sc1.

Might that be it?

Comment: Yes sorry, my mistake, just saw it myself. See follow up edit

Comment: No probs. Currently patiently waiting for the results. Seems that 500k lines gives pandas a run for its money :-P Does python behave like SQL that when running a brutal query it might never finish? How long would you say an operation like this for 500k records would take? When should I be worried? After 15 - 30 mins? Or more? EDIT: okay, looking forward to the edit.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do it, sorry, will leave the answer here for anybody to get ideas

Comment: Finally! I think I got it

Comment: I ran the code just now. Will look into it more tomorrow. But one thing that I noticed when running it on the example data is that couple of the values changed from 'xxx' to ' xxx'. But as I said, i will look into it more and get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: So after around 45 minuts the code finished running and it's not ideal. Which is my bad because of the simplistic example. The script concats every sub category to every category which with my full dataset resulted in 1099 columns, instead of cca 60 anticipated. (it should only concat existing pairs) Also, the run time is really really slow. When I run the full solution in SQL it finishes in like 15 minutes, and it consists of like 10 operations like this one. Anyways, as I said before, I very much appreciate your effort and I'm glad I learned quite a lot from your example.